# "Too few parameters error" when trying to open a recordset in Access with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2016

I found [another answer on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445062/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1-access-2007#) that addressed this but it didn't help me. I checked the query I am trying to reference and I don't see a problem with any field. I also played around with how I declared and set the objects and stuff but that didn't work either.

```
Dim dbsCurrent As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_FilmZip")
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset 'The error points to this line

rad_full = rst!radius_full

MsgBox ("rad_full:" + rad_full)
```

---

**Update:** I tried giving the .OpenRecordSet method the name of the query like this: `Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset("qry_FilmZip")`

...but now it gives me a new error: `Run-time error 3421: Data type conversion error`. Anyone know what is going on? The error points to the same line.

I found out how to resolve the 2nd error. It turns out that I had to do

```
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
```

...but I don't understand what this is really doing. Could someone enlighten me?

The SQL:

```
SELECT 

  tbl_FilmZipInfo.ID, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.item, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.qty_per_unit, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.unit_of_measure, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.radius_core, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.radius_full, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.Lf_value_for_zipper, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.S_value_for_zipper, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.film_or_zip, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.Comments, 
  tbl_FilmZipInfo.physical_description

FROM 

  tbl_FilmZipInfo

WHERE 

  (((tbl_FilmZipInfo.item)=[Forms]![frm_FilmZip]![Text314]));
```

Comment: It is `Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()` as @Tom points out.

Comment: 'Too few parameters' error points out the query expect a parameter it did not receive. I suggest you post the SQL, that's where the parameter is expected...

Comment: @marlan added the SQL

Comment: Assuming all the fields  in `tbl_FilmZipInfo` are actually there, and correctly spelled, make sure `frm_FilmZip` is loaded, and that field `Text314` is correctly spelled, and has a value.

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx

The only required argument here is the name of the recordset that you want to open.

> expression .OpenRecordset(Name, Type, Options, LockEdit)

In a parameter query like yours, you need to use the following syntax:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef 'You don't dim your qdf
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Get the parameter query
Set qfd = dbs.QueryDefs("qryMyParameterQuery")

'Supply the parameter value
qdf.Parameters("EnterStartDate") = Date
qdf.Parameters("EnterEndDate") = Date + 7

'Open a Recordset based on the parameter query
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset() 'Note the brackets here
```

You could also try the following type here:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Open a table-type Recordset
Set rsTable = dbs.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenTable)

'Open a dynaset-type Recordset using a saved query
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryMyQuery", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: The saved query I'm using doesn't prompt for a parameter. For one of the fields I grab a value from a form by using the "Cirteria" field (in Design View). Is that the same thing as a parameter?

Comment: If the query can't access the value from the form, it will treat the field as a parameter. Is this form loaded? is the value where in should be?