# Too few parameters Expected 1, when using parameters for input

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have `Too Few Parameters Expected 1` error on `Set rst = qry.OpenRecordSet`

I have spent last night and this morning to figure this out. I am in desperate help. 
The field names on query are not wrong. 
I use parameters to ask for input when running a query. But I don't think it is causeing the issue. Any advice would be highly appreciated!

SQL:

```
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_RecapByProductLineWhse.DollarsSold) AS DollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_RecapByProductLineWhse
HAVING (((dbo_SO_RecapByProductLineWhse.Period)=[Enter the month in two digits]) AND ((dbo_SO_RecapByProductLineWhse.Year)=[Enter the year in four digits]));
```

My entire code is

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function TRANS()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim acRng As Variant
    Dim xlRow As Integer

    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\M\Desktop\August 2017.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Totals")

    xlRow = (xlWS.Columns("K").End(xlDown).Row)

    Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DollarsSold")
    Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset

    Dim c As Integer
    c = 11   'C is the one that stores column number, in which c=1 means column A, 11 is for column K, 12 for Column L
    xlRow = xlRow + 11

    Do Until rst.EOF
        For Each acRng In rst.Fields
            xlWS.Cells(xlRow, c).Formula = acRng
            c = c + 1
        Next acRng
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
        c = 1
        rst.MoveNext
        If xlRow > 25 Then GoTo rq_Exit
    Loop

rq_Exit:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close acSaveYes
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Is the error msg shown **after** Access asks for the two parameters ("Enter ...")?

Comment: @Andre After inputing those parameters, I run the VBA code. then I get the error message. I have done "Table.Period="08" ,  "Table.Year="2017"  and run the vba code, still gives me the same error message.

Comment: @Andre thank you for your response. And please don't hesistate to ask me any follow-up question

Comment: Is this the complete query? With no GROUP BY, you would normally use WHERE instead of HAVING. And this query will never give more than one record, so I'm not sure why you have a `Do Until rst.EOF` loop in your VBA.

Comment: @Andre What you just said makes a lot of sense. My query is just a number, 12345.32, which is the sum of Table.DollarsSold.

Comment: Ok. About the parameters, I'm still not sure what exactly you do. If you open the query `DollarsSold` manually, and enter the parameters there, and **then** run the VBA function, the querydef in there knows nothing about the previously opened query. You will have to supply the parameters in VBA, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117093/3820271

Comment: @Andre Thank you! I did try 'Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset()' now it's giving me 'Too few parameters. Expected 2.'  Thank you so much for being patient with me.

Comment: Instead of dynamic input popup, reference controls on form for user input. I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I construct SQL string in VBA that reference form controls. However, if you really just want a single value returned, a DSum() domain aggregate function could serve instead of all that recordset code. The query returns 1 field and 1 record so why looping code? Just set the cell to value returned by DSum().

Comment: @June7 Makes sense. I didn't know about DSum() domain aggregate function. Thank you for telling me that. Will do! Thank you so much for the advice!