# Wrong number of Parameters for SQL Update Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to add an ID from different table to the table `RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP`

```
strSQL = "UPDATE RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP 
          SET RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP.ID_FZG = TI_IDENTIFIKATION.ID_FZG,
              RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP.ID_PULK = TI_IDENTIFIKATION.ID_PULK 
              WHERE RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP.ARP = TI_IDENTIFIKATION.ARP 
              AND RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP.BTNR = TI_IDENTIFIKATION.BTNR;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Returns an Error 3061 saying that it expected 4 parameters and got to few.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where are the values from "TI_IDENTIFIKATION" coming from?

Comment: You have no FROM...

Comment: looked at this? same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445062/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1-access-2007

Comment: @Stix, The values from TI_IDENTIFIKATION are from a table linked with ODBC from an Oracle server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join TI_INDENTIFICATION.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE ruser
          SET ruser.ID_FZG = ti.ID_FZG,
              ruser.ID_PULK = ti.ID_PULK
          FROM RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP ruser
          INNER JOIN TI_IDENTIFIKATION ti
                  ON ruser.ARP = ti.ARP AND ruser.BTNR = ti.BTNR;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `JOIN` be before the `SET` in Access?  `UPDATE RUSER_KSP_S_TI_ARP rUser INNER JOIN TI_IDENTIFIKATION ti ON ruser.ARP = ti.ARP AND ruser.BTNR = ti.BTNR
SET ruser.ID_FZG = ti.ID_FZG, ruser.ID_PULK = ti.ID_PULK`

Comment: Not in e.g. MS SQL

Comment: Fair enough, but the tag is Access.

Comment: To be fair, it was also tagged with other RDBMS before the edits.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook You are right, the Join needs to be before the SET. Then it works. Thanks

Comment: @Jacob  So tempted to reply - _to be fair_ and _to be honest_ always gets a rise out of me - makes me wonder what other way there is?  _to be unfair_ or _to be dishonest_? :D

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Like *unfair enough*? :)

Comment: Yep, definitely _unfair enough_.  Didn't say I don't use them... just always gets a rise out of me.