# MS Access Query into Excel, "Too Few Parameters. Expected 1"

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm using MS Office 2016.

I see my queries are working fine in MS Access, but when I tried to get the query into the MS Excel, I receive the message

> Too few parameters. Expected 1.

I use `Data > Get External Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query` and choose the query that I want to connect to Excel.

The query that I want to connect from Access is

```
SELECT A.*, B.[Attainment Legacy]
FROM Final_Report_Union AS A LEFT JOIN 004_Product_Master_View AS B 
ON A.[Family]=B.[Planning Part];
```

Any idea why Excel displays this message?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1. (Access 2007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445062/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1-access-2007)

Comment: The typical source for this error is a misspelled or missing field or table name.